# How to access and display all Liferay forms from a specific user

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-dxp, liferay-7.1

We want users to be able to view the forms that they have filled in while they're logged in. How could we use Liferay Forms to achieve this or how could we use DDL to access the forms?

We thought to access the user id and then return the forms associated with that id however we're not sure how to approach this solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think spring portlet good approach for you
[enter link description here](https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/7-1/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/t/configuring-a-spring-mvc-portlet)
configure with spring security or access liferay user services and manage and authorize your views or portlets

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look into it and then get back to you on it

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through permission settings.
Go on Site > Content > Form > Form's specific Settings (...) > Permissions.

You have to create a new Role and add only user who wants to see this Form. From Form's Permission setting you can control to whom you want to show the form.

[image]